# How to serialize "12/19/2013 12:00:00 AM" to DateTime Type on C# using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I'm currently using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class but I cannot convert dates like `12/19/2013 12:00:00 AM` to a C# `DateTime` Object.

The error that I'm getting says:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   Uptivity.achievement. DateTime content '12/19/2013 12:00:00 AM' does
>   not start with 'Date(' and end with ')' as required for JSON.

in:

```
    public static T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
    {

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return obj;
    }
```

I've been trying to  define the datetime format like this:

```
     public static T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
     {

       var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeFormat = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeFormat("G")
        };

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T),settings);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return obj;
      }
```

But now I'm receiving:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   Uptivity.achievement. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Also this `12/19/2013 12:00:00 AM` format like Date is the one that the json provider is delivering.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you include what you've tried.  Have you tried correcting this: '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.

Comment: Thanks i will update my post asap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640096/datacontractjsonserializer-date-serialization

Answer (score 3):

After some troubleshooting i come up with this as my solution:

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
    public static T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        T obj = ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);

        return obj;
    }
```

And now it's running smoothly.